# How can I make my mouseenter function not execute if it's already executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, jquery-events

**Simple problem:** so I have a `mouseenter` function

```
    $('.filmstrip').bind('mouseenter',function(){
        var isStopped = false;
        var $that = $(this),
               w = $that.width(),
              fr = $that.attr('data-framerate');
        $that.css('background-position',$that.attr('data-placeholderXStart') + ' center');
        $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-gifurl')+')');
        for ( var i = 1, n = $that.attr('data-ticks'); i <= n && !isStopped; ++i )
        {
            (function(j){
               setTimeout(function(){
                  if (!isStopped) {
                      $that.css('background-position','-'+(w*j)+'px center');
                  }
               }, j*fr);
            })(i);
        }
        $that.bind('mouseleave',function(){
            isStopped = true;
            $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-placeholder')+')').css('background-position',$that.attr('data-placeholderXStart') + ' center');
        });
        
    });
```

and I want it to execute only if it's not already in the process of executing. The reason is because I don't want someone to re-hover over the thing and make it start while it's still animating.

Comment: Put `isStopped` outside the event handler.

Comment: @adeneo So make it a global variable?

Comment: That depends on the scope outside the event handler. Personally I'd use jQuery's `data()`. The variable does however need to persist outside the event handler, so if the handler is fired again it knows that the animation is ongoing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable which indicate the status of function associated with mouse enter event

```
    var isMouseEnterRunning = false;
    $('.filmstrip').bind('mouseenter',function(){

        if(!isMouseEnterRunning){ 
            isMouseEnterRunning = true;   
            var isStopped = false;
            var $that = $(this),
                   w = $that.width(),
                  fr = $that.attr('data-framerate');
            $that.css('background-position',$that.attr('data-placeholderXStart') + ' center');
            $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-gifurl')+')');
            for ( var i = 1, n = $that.attr('data-ticks'); i <= n && !isStopped; ++i )
            {
                (function(j){
                   setTimeout(function(){
                      if (!isStopped) {
                          $that.css('background-position','-'+(w*j)+'px center');
                      }
                   }, j*fr);
                })(i);
            }
            $that.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                isStopped = true;
                $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-placeholder')+')').css('background-position',$that.attr('data-placeholderXStart') + ' center');
            });
            isMouseEnterRunning = false;
        }
});
```